# Getting Canon imageFORMULA R10 to work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, scanner, canon

I need to get my Canon imageFORMULA R10 scanner working on Ubuntu 20.04. However, Canon does not have an official driver for this particular scanner and VueScan didn't work with it either. I was wondering if there's another way to get it to work on my OS.

Also here's a link to the model if that helps: https://www.amazon.ca/Canon-imageFORMULA-Document-Scanner-4861C001/dp/B08FBHTD9B/

I look forward to hearing any suggestions you all may have.

Comment: If it has no native support (yet) with open-source drivers, no support form the manufacturer with proprietary drivers and also no supported by the commercial solution, what excatly are you expecting from here?

Comment: The slim chance that someone had a solution I haven't thought of yet.